# QDataWidgetMapper does not update in all Windows

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I'm trying to get a multi window application in PyQt to work which should display in more than one window the data in different ways. Now I'm running into an issue I don't understand with the *QDataWidgetMapper*. To explain I've created a sample application.
The code below does create

- A connection to an SQLite DB
- Creates two identical Windows showing a *QTable* and a *QlineEdit* which is mapped on cell 0,0

  ```
  import sys
  from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
  from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView, QMessageBox,\
  QLineEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QDataWidgetMapper
  from Singleton import Singleton

  class SqlModel(QSqlTableModel, metaclass=Singleton):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
          con.setDatabaseName("chinook.sqlite")
          con.open()
          super().__init__()

  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 200))
          widget = QWidget()        
          layout = QVBoxLayout()
          widget.setLayout(layout)
          self.setCentralWidget(widget)

          self.table = QTableView()
          layout.addWidget(self.table)

          self.inputField = QLineEdit()
          layout.addWidget(self.inputField)

          self.model = SqlModel()
          self.model.setTable("Track")
          print(self.model.lastError().text())

          self.table.setModel( self.model )

          print(self.model.lastError().text())

          self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
          self.mapper.setModel(self.model)

          self.mapper.addMapping(self.inputField, 0)

          self.model.select()
          self.mapper.toFirst()

  def createConnection():
      con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
      con.setDatabaseName("chinook.sqlite")
      if not con.open():
          print('could not open db')
          return False
      return True


  app = QApplication(sys.argv)

  window = MainWindow()
  window.show()

  window2 = MainWindow()
  window2.show()

  app.exec_()
  ```

Both Windows do open.
Both *QTables* do synchronize perfectly.
**BUT ONLY one** *LineEdit* in one of the Windows does follow any value changes, the *QLineEdit* in the other window is just displaying the intial value upn open without any further action.

Just for completeness the code of the Singleton Class:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

class Singleton(type(QObject), type):
    '''
    :class: Parent class used to build the individial singletons across the program. 
    '''
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):  # @NoSelf @ReservedAssignment
        super().__init__(name, bases, dict)
        cls._instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # @NoSelf
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

Comment: You're calling `select()` twice. You need to re-organise your code so that it [separates the concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of the model from the windows. As it is, the setup for the model is carried out during the initialisation of the windows, *so everrything gets done twice*. Do all the setup for the model inside its own `__init__` (which only gets called once, since it's a singleton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The problem is trivial but difficult to track but I am going to explain it step by step, but before doing so you have to understand that:

- If you reset a model set to a mapper then the currentIndex will be -1.
- Using select() resets the QSqlTableModel.

Steps:

- In the first MainWindow you create the model (SqlModel), you set the model on the view (QTableView) and the mapper (QDataWidgetMapper), then you use select () and set the currentIndex of the mapper to be 0.
- In the second MainWindow it is no longer necessary to create the module since the Singleton uses the cache, you set it in the view and the mapper, you call select that will set the currentIndex to -1 to the mapper of the first MainWindow, and then you set the currentIndex to 0 of the second mapper.

**In conclusion:** The currentIndex of the mapper of the first window will be -1 and instead the currentIndex of the second mapper is 0, so the first QLineEdit is not updated since it does not have an assigned row. The problem is caused by calling select() twice which resets the mappers of the previous windows.

### Solution:

One possible solution is to only use `select()` once:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 200))
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.table = QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.inputField = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.inputField)

        self.model = SqlModel()

        if not getattr(self.model, "is_loaded", False):
            self.model.setTable("Track")
            if not self.model.select():
                print(self.model.lastError().text())
            self.model.is_loaded = True

        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)

        self.mapper.addMapping(self.inputField, 0)

        self.mapper.toFirst()
```

Another possible solution is that the information load (set the table and use select()) is done in the constructor.

Comment: thank you very much! 
Both of your proposals are working perfectly.